# jQuery - Pausing and resuming a looping animation too quickly causes the queue to go haywire

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that animates forever, pauses at the end of the current animation on mouse enter, and resumes on mouse leave. It works how I want it to except for one issue.

If I hover in and out of the element too quickly (e.g. by cutting across the corner) it causes some kind of queue build up and everything goes haywire. However when I actually check the queue there's nothing strange in it and the animations are obviously not even running in the queued order.

Using the following code waggle your mouse in and out of the grey area. When you eventually allow the animations to resume they will go haywire (also available at http://jsfiddle.net/54YTx/).

```
$('body').html('<div style="background: lightgrey;">Testing</div>');

function do_animations() {
    // Always 0 or 1
    console.log($('div').queue('fx').length);

    $('div')
        .delay(1000)
        // Hardcoded numbers mean that resuming from the bottom position takes longer but it doesn't matter in this simple example
        .animate({'padding-top': '100px'}, 1000)
        .animate({'padding-top': '0px'}, 1000)
        // Queue instead of callback so that clearQueue() can stop the loop reliably
        .queue(function() {
            do_animations();
            $('div').dequeue();
        });
};
do_animations();

$('div').hover(function() {
    // Don't use stop(). We want the current animation to finish
    $('div').clearQueue();
}, function() {
    do_animations();
});​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `clearQueue()` might be buggy with animations. If in the original code I removed the `clearQueue()` then no matter what I did I couldn't get the animations to go out of sync. Of course I couldn't stop the animations either. I delved into the jQuery source and the queue is definitely cleared but jQuery is still pulling the animations from somewhere so it could be closure related or something. Sometimes `clearQueue()` even seemed to be not clearing `delay()`.

I found the most bulletproof solution was to just use `setTimeout`/`clearTimeout` like the old days. Maybe I don't understand the jQuery queue but I never had problems with it in the past.

(Also available at http://jsfiddle.net/QkpE6/)

```
$('body').html('<div style="background: lightgrey;">Testing</div>');

function play() {
    timer = setTimeout(do_animations, 2000);
}

function pause() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
}

function do_animations() {
    var padding = ($('div').css('padding-top') == '0px') ? '100px' : '0px';

    $('div')
        .queue(function() {
            $(this).animate(
                {'padding-top': padding},
                {duration: 1000, queue: false}
            ).dequeue();
        }).queue(function() {
            play();
            $(this).dequeue();
        });
};
play();

$('div').hover(function() { 
    pause();
}, function() {
    play();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With clearQueue you remove all steps from the queue, but your first animations are not IN the queue.
So you remove only the repeating callback.
When moving the mouse fast in and out, a stack of your 2 animations is piled up with every mouseIn.

adding a `.stop()` just before your delay() might do the trick as well without harming your queue because it simply removes all other animations on this element.

You have to change it so that the 2 animations are queued even when they are done the first time.

---

I know thats only an example, but in your hove event you should use: `$(this).clearQueue();` if you have more than only one div on your page.

Comment: I thought that ``animate()`` went into the ``fx`` queue by default? ``stop()`` kills the loop and I changed all my ``$(this)`` to ``$('div')`` to be sure that I was targeting the right queue.

Comment: `stop()` : _Description: Stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements._  So by adding stop you do: stop animations / wait, animate to 100 / animate to 0 / queue to start over again.  have you tried to change your code?

Comment: Yes, I did try it and like I said it kills the loop. There is a jsfiddle in my question where you can also test against my code.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, missed the fiddle

se my changes:
http://jsfiddle.net/snS78/

now every next step is a callback for the last.
That seems to solve the problem.

```
...
$('#jumpy')
    .delay(1000)
    .stop()
    // Hardcoded numbers mean that resuming from the bottom position takes longer but it doesn't matter in this simple example
    .animate({'padding-top': '100px'}, 1000,
             function(){
                $(this).animate({'padding-top': '0px'}, 1000,
                         function(){
                            $(this).queue(function() {
                                do_animations();
                                $('#jumpy').dequeue();
                            })
                         })
              });
...
```

Comment: This solves one issue but reintroduces another issue that is mentioned in the comments of the original jsfiddle. ``clearQueue`` will not prevent the callback which means that if you hover over the element while it is animated it will not be paused.

Comment: ok and sorry, I'm out. tried to make it work but wasn't successful. I would have gone without queue and data/classes to mark the last step (up/down)